# android:ksoap issue

Tags: android-ksoap2

I am new in Androi. I use the ksoap for web service.There is two input float values are there in web service request but return the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 67.296652
```

then i set to int for testing, but then after during the response i get the error

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector
```

I have reference code from http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the answer, when we add the new data type like double or date then need to create the new classes the answer is here, http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html